# Mass assignment won't handle Null input even when default is set on migration.Any solution to this?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mass-assignment

I have been using mass assignment a lot. I recently came across this issue, where I create fillable, and also defaults for null values, but on using mass assignment, if my inputs are empty, it returns a "Cannot Be Null" Error.

**My Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['name','status'];
```

**My Controller**

```
$this->model->create($request->all());
```

**My Migration**

```
$table->boolean('status')->default(0);
```

Shouldn't the above mean that when I provide nothing on the input field `status`, it should default to 0? But column can't be `null` is thrown.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: `0` in NOT a `null`. Your migration does not set field nullable.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this myself.  Take a look in your **app\Http\Kernel.php** file.  There is a Laravel middleware that is converting your empty inputs into null values.  So, even though you've correctly got the mass assignment set up, and the migration defaulting to 0, this middleware is changing the value before it gets to those points.  The code you are looking for is similar to:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class, // <<-- This one
];
```

You can remove it, or leave it in and write a method to compensate for all inputs.  I simply removed this and then set a mutator to do what the middleware did for those inputs I wanted to be null.

HTH

Comment: yes, but I am using boolean, and when I don't convertEmptyStringToNull, I am passing an empty string, for boolean, and still doesn't default to 0 from my migration. What can be done for this?

Comment: Add a mutator on the model.  If the value comes in empty or null, set the value to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have the problem because of `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware which was added to laravel >= 5.4. This middleware convert all empty strings to `null`. So if You don't set any value to `status` field it will be `null`. Your migration isn't `->nullable()` so there is thrown error `Cannot Be Null`.

You can resolve it like this:

```
$all = $request->all();

if(is_null($request->get('status')))
{
     unset($all['status']);
}

$this->model->create($all);
```

Comment: @Manishbasnyat182 I added solution for your case.

Comment: i could tweak in something as such but I was only searching for an option where I woudn't have go through these checks. Thanks for your help though.